# Horizontal view for the Network tab on DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I know it's possible to make this from the `Settings -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Panel Layout` but that only applies to the `Elements` tab. Is there a way to apply that to the Network tab as well?

Elements tab:

[image: element tab view]

Network tab:

[image: network tab view]

Comment: No, it's not implemented. You can try to do it manually in [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138).

Comment: That seems good, but it won't persist. I'd need something that persists :/

Comment: You can do it by putting the CSS into a [devtools theme extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/search/devtools%20theme). Get an existing one, make a copy, put your CSS there, use "load unpacked" in chrome://extensions, enable devtools -> settings -> experiments -> custom stylesheets. There may be also an extension that allows to input your custom CSS directly without the need to modify the extension itself.